# Quote a tweet with Twitter API by using Python

Tags: python, twitter

I can retweet a tweet by using the tweepy library. But what I want to do is to quote a tweet. I can’t find anything about it.

Answer (score 3):

To post a quote Tweet, you include the link to the original Tweet in the body of the new Tweet you are posting.